# AttributeError: module 'web3.geth' has no attribute 'txpool'

Tags: python, web3py, go-ethereum

When I call

```
provider = Web3.HTTPProvider('some url')
w3 = Web3(provider)
web3.geth.txpool.inspect()
```

I get an error

```
AttributeError: module 'web3.geth' has no attribute 'txpool'
```

My geth config

```
--http --http.api eth,net,web3,txpool
```

**Why I can't access txpool?**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `web3.geth.txpool.inspect` I had to use `w3.geth.txpool.inspect()`